# Python прокси сервер для конкретного приложения

Tags: python, python-3.x, proxy

Подскажите, возможно ли используя python направлять все запросы конкретного приложения через прокси сервер? Прокси поддерживает HTTP, HTTPS, SOCKS и для подключения использует логин и пароль. В сети попался материал 
 `https://github.com/deactivated/proxifier` и я не совсем понял, подходит он для моей задачи или нет. Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Под приложением вы понимаете любое стороннее приложение или написанное вами?

Comment: Любое стороннее приложение, не имеющее настроек работы с прокси сервером.

Answer (score 1):

Прокси с авторизацией выглядит так:

```py
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth

url = 'http://google.com/' #запрос
proxies = {'http': 'ваш ip или адрес:ваш порт'} #пара ключ-значение
auth = HTTPProxyAuth('ваш логин', 'ваш пароль') #авторизация

response = requests.get(url=url, proxies=proxies, auth=auth) #get http запрос
response.close() #закрытие подключения

print(response.status_code) # 200 - good
```

Comment: Все верно. Я бымог обойтись имеющейся в windows программой netsh winhttp set proxy SERVER:PORT, но увы, она вроде как не позволяет использовать логин и пароль для прокси подключений. Ситуация требует работы с конкретным windows приложением. Реально ли осуществлять "проксификацию" указанного приложения? Возможно в python имеются какие-либо компоненты для подобных задач.